# Erro na minificação de imagens com Gulp no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, gulp, gulpjs

estou tentando fazer o gulp minificar as imagens do meu projeto. Meu projeto é o laravel 5.3 e estou usando a lib [laravel-elixir-imagemin](https://github.com/nathanmac/laravel-elixir-imagemin) do gulp para minificar, só que quando dou o comando `gulp imagemin` aparece o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que ele não reconhece a pasta `resources/assets/images` de origem e diz que não minificou nenhuma imagem. Enfim, já tentei diversas configurações para o gulp e nada.

Segue o código:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const watch = require('gulp-watch');
require('laravel-elixir-imagemin');

elixir.config.sourcemaps = true;

elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.imagemin();
    mix.scripts(
        [
            'vendor/jquery.js',
            'vendor/bootstrap.js',
            'script.js'
        ],
        'public/js/app.js');


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta, o problema era que para esse plugin em especial é necessário setar as configurações, já que ele não possui uma configuração default como eu acredirei que tinha.

Bastou colocar esse código:

```
elixir.config.images = {
    folder: 'img',
    outputFolder: 'img'
};
```